# what role does network bridge `docker0` play in k8s with flannel

Tags: kubernetes, flannel

> k8s version: v1.10.4
>   flannel version: v0.10.0
>   docker version v1.12.6

when i use command `brctl show` on node,it shows as bellow:

```
[root@node03 tmp]# brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
cni0        8000.0a580af40501   no      veth39711246
                                        veth591ea0bf
                                        veth5b889fed
                                        veth61dfc48a
                                        veth6ef58804
                                        veth75f5ef36
                                        vethc162dc8a
docker0     8000.0242dfd605c0   no
```

it shows that the vethXXX are binding on network bridge named cni0, but when i use command `ip addr`,it shows :

```
[root@node03 tmp]# ip addr |grep veth
6: veth61dfc48a@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue master cni0 state UP 
7: veth591ea0bf@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue master cni0 state UP 
9: veth6ef58804@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue master cni0 state UP 
46: vethc162dc8a@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue master cni0 state UP 
55: veth5b889fed@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue master cni0 state UP 
61: veth75f5ef36@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue master cni0 state UP 
78: veth39711246@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue master cni0 state UP
```

these veth are all binding on `if3` ,but `if3` is not cni0.it is `docker0`

```
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN
```

it seems that network bridge `docker0` is useless, but `ip addr` shows that all veth device are binding on it . what role does network bridge `docker0` play in k8s with flannel? thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are two network models here Docker and Kubernetes.

Docker model

> By default, Docker uses host-private networking. It creates a virtual bridge, called `docker0` by default, and allocates a subnet from one of the private address blocks defined in [RFC1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) for that bridge. For each container that Docker creates, it allocates a virtual Ethernet device (called `veth`) which is attached to the bridge. The veth is mapped to appear as `eth0` in the container, using Linux namespaces. The in-container `eth0` interface is given an IP address from the bridge’s address range.
>
> **The result is that Docker containers can talk to other containers only if they are on the same machine** (and thus the same virtual bridge). **Containers on different machines can not reach each other** - in fact they may end up with the exact same network ranges and IP addresses.

Kubernetes model

> Kubernetes imposes the following fundamental requirements on any networking implementation (barring any intentional network segmentation policies):

- all containers can communicate with all other containers without NAT
- all nodes can communicate with all containers (and vice-versa) without NAT
- the IP that a container sees itself as is the same IP that others see it as

> Kubernetes applies IP addresses at the  `Pod`  scope - containers within a  `Pod`  share their network namespaces - including their IP address. This means that containers within a  `Pod`  can all reach each other’s ports on  `localhost`. This does imply that containers within a  `Pod`  must coordinate port usage, but this is no different than processes in a VM. This is called the “IP-per-pod” model. This is implemented, using Docker, as a “pod container” which holds the network namespace open while “app containers” (the things the user specified) join that namespace with Docker’s  `--net=container:<id>`  function.
>
> As with Docker, it is possible to request host ports, but this is reduced to a very niche operation. In this case a port will be allocated on the host  `Node`  and traffic will be forwarded to the  `Pod`. The  `Pod`  itself is blind to the existence or non-existence of host ports.

In order to integrate the platform with the underlying network infrastructure Kubernetes provide a plugin specification called [Container Networking Interface (CNI)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/). If the Kubernetes fundamental requirements are met vendors can use network stack as they like, typically using overlay networks to support **multi-subnet** and **multi-az** clusters.

Bellow is shown how overlay networks are implemented through [Flannel](https://github.com/coreos/flannel) which is a popular [CNI](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/).

[image: flannel]

You can read more about other CNI's [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/#how-to-implement-the-kubernetes-networking-model). The Kubernetes approach is explained in [Cluster Networking](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/) docs. I also recommend reading [Kubernetes Is Hard: Why EKS Makes It Easier for Network and Security Architects](https://www.contino.io/insights/kubernetes-is-hard-why-eks-makes-it-easier-for-network-and-security-architects) which explains how [Flannel](https://github.com/coreos/flannel) works, also another [article from Medium](https://medium.com/all-things-about-docker/setup-hyperd-with-flannel-network-1c31a9f5f52e)

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

The @if3 in a veth interface is the peer interface index at the other end of the veth pair. In this case, it's the interface 3 inside a pod network namespace. If you exec into a pod and do `ip addr`, you can see interface 3 is normally eth0 inside the pod.

So this interface index 3 has nothing to do with local interface index, which in your case, happening to be docker0.

> 7: veth591ea0bf@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450
> qdisc noqueue **master cni0** state UP

The `master cni0` shows that the veth interface is connected to bridge cni0 in the host/root namespace.